# How do I use small capitals in the title of a document of class article?

Tags: titles, article, small-caps

I want to use small capitals in the title of my LaTeX document (of class `article`), which is all capitals by default. The following MWE does not give the expected results (it does nothing):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,cite,url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref} 

\title{\textsc{Small capitals}: Rest of the title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: When I compile your document, I get the following ouput:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/14ozW.png Also I can't confirm the "all capitals by default".

Comment: @leandriis Hm. This is a conference paper, and there is a specific package that we must use that I left out in the MWE. That must be it then. Any ideas how to force small capitals anyway?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could specify which "special package" you must use.

Comment: It's called `ismir`, and is part of the template provided.

Comment: Well, if you want to submit to this conference, then it might be best to not alter their stylistic choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an comment you  mentioned `ismir.sty` which I guess comes from [here](https://github.com/ismir/ismir2016-lbd/blob/9c007564cc39ac8e154ec80e112bddadc89c8db7/templates/ISMIR2016-LBD_tex_template.zip).

In that case you did not tell us that you added `\usepackage{ismir}` in your code.

Now the culprit is that `ismir.sty` uses

```
\def\@maketitle{
  \newpage
  \null
  \begin{center} {
    \Large \bf \uppercase \@title \par % <===============================
  }
  \vskip 2.0em {
    \large \lineskip .5em
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    \@author \\
    \end{tabular}
    \par
  }
  \end{center}
  \par
  \vskip 2.0em
}
```

An combination of `\uppercase` and `\textsc` makes no sense, so only `\uppercase` is used.

As far as I see you have only two possibilitys:

1. Use the given template if you want to submit an paper to them without any changings
2. if you not have to submit an article to them use another template or simply `article` to build your document. Then you can use `\textsc` in the title as shown in your mwe, **that does not include package `ismir`**.

Without `ismir` (commented) the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,cite,url}
%\usepackage{ismir} % <==================================================
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref} 

\title{\textsc{Small capitals}: Rest of the title}
\author{Author}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
text.
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: result without ismir]

and with `ismir.sty` you get:

[image: result with ismir]

Please see that that template seems to be very old, it still uses `\bf`.  You should contact the maintainer to get it updated ...

Comment: I already figured out that my problem is due to my usage of the `ismir` package, but I now understand why it occurs. I'll ask if I am allowed to edit it. Thanks for flagging the usage of `\bf`, I will address that!

Answer (score 0):

Your MWE works for me. I get

```
SMALL CAPITALS: Rest of the title
```

where `SMALL CAPITALS` is set in small caps (capital S, lower case small caps the rest). I don't understand your problem. GOM

Comment: See my comment on leandriis's comment above. (I don't know what GOM means, by the way.)

Comment: @rdv GOM = Grumpy Old Man

Comment: @rdv Please, the next time you provide an MWE test it first to be sure that it shows your problem. Being a GOM I don't like to waste my time.